# How would I check which number a selected item is in a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox

I have a combobox with 15 items in it right now. I want to be able to check if I've selected item number 1 for example, or item number 7. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do it and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you mean [`ComboBox.SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property [ComboBox.SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int selected = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
```

Note that indices are zero-based, this means that if you have selected the first element, `selected` would be `0`. If you selected the fourth one, it'd be `3`, and so on.